# joomla backend nothing shown on any task

Tags: joomla, controller, admin

Can somebody give me a clue on what's happening here. It is strange that PHP gives me no error, nor warning, anything at all.. but it does not work..

here is my last set of changes https://bitbucket.org/brankito/making-chat-app-in-joomla/commits/71281244694631463b45853563ad1d2913ca74e4#Ladministrator/components/com_explore/views/activities/tmpl/default.phpT10

, when i load url which loads my list view in backend, [view=activities], it's all ok, i see my toolbar, and published [green checkmark] buttons, but when i click unpublish on any item, or select more of them and click unpublish in toolbar area, instead of doing that action and returning me back on same view, my browser shows url correctly but i get nothing in my view, no list, and no toolbar icons, no errors from php at all, so i dont have a clue where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're loosing your view after submitting form, try to replace this:

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_explore'); ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
```

with:

```
<form action="index.php?option=com_explore&view=activities" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">
```

Comment: thanks di3sel, for your quick response, but as you can see in a red diff line above the JRoute one, that was exactly like you proposed, in a previous commit.. still it happened the very same thing, which is why i tried with JRoute..!